# PHP warning :PHP Startup:pdf:Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, code-generation, pdflib

After changer the pdflib form V9 to V8 i have this issue

```
PHP Startup:pdf:Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525 PHP 
compiled with module API=20131226 These options need to match
```

How can i fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Module compiled with module API=20100525 PHP
```

this means you use the DSO for PHP 5.4, however your new PHP version is PHP 5.6. This new version is not not supported by the old and outdated PDFlib 8. So you have to stay at the current PDFlib 9, where the download packages contain the required DSO (on almost all platforms)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use V8 anymore.
It will only work with PHP 5.2-5.4 ([see here](http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-8/), below the first table), and your PHP version looks like 5.6 or 5.7 and in my humble opinion, you should keep it that way.
Is something wrong with V9?